# No module named pipreqs.__main__; 'pipreqs' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module, requirements.txt

I am trying to use pipreqs module to generate requirements text. But pipreqs is generating following error.

```
No module named pipreqs.__main__; 'pipreqs' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and trying to use pipreqs by following command in Terminal.

```
python -m pipreqs [location/project]
```

I've already installed pipreqs and also updated pip. But still the problem remains. Is it a bug or am I doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: that is a bug, but you can work around it by calling it as `python -m pipreqs.pipreqs  [location/project]`

Comment: cool... that works!! thanks man.

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks you so much! You saved my day! (And probably my night as well!)

Comment: @Copperfield you should post that a solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a bug, but you can work around it by calling it as `python -m pipreqs.pipreqs [location/project]`

The reason of the the problem is that they didn't include a [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) in the module that python expect when calling a package (a folder with an `__init__.py` and some other .py files if any) directly, which is like the `if __name__=='__main__':...` for modules, but need to be explicit for package.